# Handling two different functions with the same name in Doxygen

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

I have a C project which contains two functions with the same name, but each is within a different group/module (`@defgroup`).

These functions each compile into a different binary, but I need the documentation to be closely cross-referenced, so I need to refer (`@ref`) to these functions (among other places) from each other's module.

When I do simple `@ref name-of-the-function`, it always links to the one which resides in file which is earlier in the file tree. How can I link to the other one?

Comment: what about the obvious: can you rename the functions, to avoid the name clash?

Comment: @JörgBeyer No. Those are parts of APIs I have to provide (and I have to provide both of them).

Comment: You have C APIs with identically-named functions?  I think Doxygen will be the last of your problems...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth As I said, each of the functions goes into a different binary (and both APIs are set in stone). This is for university assignment, where we are writing an operating system and we have to provide two variations of malloc and free. One is within kernel (but the internal API is prescribed) and one is for user applications (the API is also prescribed). The kernel is in completely different "namespace" and communicates with applications via syscalls. But the docs have to be consistent and interlinked. I simply can't affect neither. This name clash is not the only one (eg. gets..).

Comment: When refering to functions or variables you can prefix the namespace of the object with the namespace they are in followed by a `::`. For example, in C++ if I had a variable `x` in both classes `myClass1` and `myClass2`, I could uniquely refer to both of them as `myClass1::x` and `myClass2::x` respectively. I'm not sure what the namespace will be in your case (maybe the group you put it in?) so I will refrain from posting this as an answer - hopefully someone else can come along and give a full answer.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see: **doxygen's autolinking does not support having multiple functions with the same name.**

If there are multiple functions/methods with the same name, doxygen will simply link the first one it finds, as described in the question. The call graphs will also be incorrect. This seems to apply to all languages, not just to C.

This has been reported as a bug multiple times:

- [#3676 bad links in source code browser for multiple functions of same name](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/3676)
- [#5448 Different Static Functions With Same Name Confusion](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/5448)
- [#979 Mismatched documentation for functions having same name](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/979)
- [#3724 \relates confused on multiple static functions with the same name](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/3723)

The section ["Known problems"](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/trouble.html) in doxygen's docs also describes a similar problem:

> It is not possible to insert a non-member function f in a class A
>   using the \relates or \relatesalso command, if class A already has a
>   member with name f and the same argument list.

---

There is some hope; someone proposed a patch to better handle functions with the same name:  [#4365 getDefs fails to resolve local function names if same global name exist](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/4365).

> This patch implements the following two strategies for resolving
>   duplicated names. First, is the name is defined in current file, use
>   the local name. Secondly try to match the names using the prototype
>   definition.

This would partly solve the problem. Unfortunately, the ticket has seen no activity since 2012...

Answer (score 1):

can this work for you?

The example is stripped down to the two files **a.c** and **b.c**, with only one function (the clashing) function.

file a.c

```
/**
 * \defgroup agroup Group A
 */

/** 
 * the function in a, 
 * see also \link b.c myfunc() \endlink the other one 
 * \ingroup agroup
 */
void myfunc() {
    ;
}
```

file b.c

```
/**
 * \defgroup bgroup Group B
 */

/** 
 * the function in b, 
 * see also \link a.c myfunc() \endlink the other one 
 * \ingroup bgroup
 */
void myfunc() {
    ;
}
```

as you see, `myfunc()` has a name clash. I placed a link to the *other* function in the documentation.

I prepended the **function name** by the **filename**.

I compiled it with **doxygen** and the links worked (they linked from each documentation of a function to the other function).

Comment: But you are linking to the groups, not the functions, right? (the groups which contain the functions in my case contain also many other functions and extensive documentation of the subsystem represented by the group, so merely linking to the group is suboptimal).

Comment: you are right, and I updated it. I seems now to be a link to the function in the (other) file.

Comment: This seems to only link the file's page, not the function.

Comment: in that case, you can put the function in a separate file, that would keep the API as it is.

Comment: `\link <filename> <rest of link target...> <link description> \endlink` does not do what you're describing, I don't think, either according to the documentation or in practice. I don't think there can be any spaces in the link target; everything after the first space is considered part of the link description.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works for me in doxygen 1.8.13 is to provide an explicit link with the HTML `<a></a>` tag. For example, I have a function `QF_run()`, which is defined in three different files `qv.c`, `qk.c` and `qxk.c`. Here are three links to these three definitions:

```
<a href="qv_8c.html#a779a1bc9482e2d489dc87751cd100fdb"><b>QF_run()</b></a>
<a href="qk_8c.html#a779a1bc9482e2d489dc87751cd100fdb"><b>QF_run()</b></a>
<a href="qxk_8c.html#a779a1bc9482e2d489dc87751cd100fdb"><b>QF_run()</b></a>
```

These links are rendered in the HTML output the same way as the automatically generated links. The links are also stable as long as you don't change the name of the function.

To obtain the hash-value for your function, simply open its documentation in a browser and copy the link after the # sign.

Answer (score 1):

No answer but same problem with C++ enums.

We're generally lazy and copy the main.cpp from one of our CLI tool to the next... 
So they all contain:

```
enum class Command {
    USAGE,
    SOME_COMMAND,
}
```

Most of these tools are diagnostics, PoC, live test tools for libs, etc...

We build a single doc from all of our sources so the multiple declarations of this enum, even though they lie in different directories, will be found in the doc only once in the first file parsed and will contain ALL of the values declared in all the files... using clang parsing does not change anything there...

That is quite misleading. The call graphs are wrong too of course...