# Insert link to function in another file with Doxygen?

Tags: c, doxygen

I have two C source files. A comment to a function `bar()`in file `A` needs to refer to a function `foo()` in file `B`. How can I make this link?

I tried:

1. Writing something like: `B.c::foo()` hoping that doxygen would go to file `B` and find function `foo` there.
2. Also tried simply `::foo()` but that did not help.
3. Then I tried giving file `B.c` a special tagname as in doing `//! @file specialtag` on first line of `B.c` and then doing `specialtag::foo()` in my comment but not much has changed.
4. I tried to force the link with `\ref` and `\link` but even that did not help.

The `//! @file` line is present in both `A.c` and `B.c` so doxygen should be aware of the code.

**EDIT**

I tried what @doxygen suggested but with no luck. I made an example project to show where I am running into problems, its here: http://www.filedropper.com/testdoxygen2tar

I used the default setup file, made with `doxygen -g`.
The output I am getting:
[image: Firefox showing the page generated by doxygen]

You can see that the foobar function is not being linked to.

**EDIT 2**

Found the problem. Function `foo` was undocumented and so no page for it was generated, so of course doxygen had no page to link to. (I was generating documentation with the `SOURCE_BROWSER` option enabled and hoping that a link to function definition would be generated)

Comment: The best that I can think of is just a link to the file, with a BOLD note telling the user to look at the function when they get there. You can auto-link, or use @see. Sorry that this isn’t much help. I would like to know the answer myself. If no luck here, then maybe  to register and post you question to the DoxyGen users mailing list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. Here's a minimal example that works with a default configuration file (`doxygen -g`):

First create file foo.c with the following contents:

```
/** @file */

/** Function foo, see also bar(). */
void foo()
{
}
```

then create file bar.c with the following contents:

```
/** @file */

/** Function bar, see also foo(). */
void bar()
{
}
```

Run doxygen and observe in the HTML output that both functions will have a link to the other function.

Comment: I solved the issue. I was generating the documentation with `SOURCE_BROWSER`  option enabled and was hoping that a function name would take me to its source definition.

Comment: You can set EXTRACT_ALL to YES if you want placeholders to link to without documenting the function.

Comment: What if the two functions have the same name?

Comment: @beaver: That's a different question. Fortunately it's already been asked :-). [Handling two different functions with the same name in Doxygen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548701/handling-two-different-functions-with-the-same-name-in-doxygen).