# Visual studio: How to create hyperlink in comments section in c++ code to go to different lines within the code

Tags: visual-studio, hyperlink

I need to create a hyper link in my comments section of my c++ code so that , when I click on the link, it should take me to a specific line of the same code base.

That specific line could be in same file or different, but of course the same project.

Is this possible in Visual studio when writing c/c++ code.

For example,

```
int main()
{
 Marks m1(10,20);
 Marks m2(30,40);
 Marks m3,m4;

 //Line 7

std::cout <<m1.get_int_marks()<<std::endl;
std::cout << m1.get_ext_marks() << std::endl;

m3 = m1 + m2;

 //Line 14

std::cout << m3.get_int_marks() << std::endl;
std::cout << m3.get_ext_marks() << std::endl;

m4 = m1 - m2;

int x = 10 + 20;

std::cout << m4.get_int_marks() << std::endl;
std::cout << m4.get_ext_marks() << std::endl;

std::cout << x << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

In the above code , can I create a hyperlink in the comments, at line 7 to go to line 14.

Used case can be to go to any line of any file in the project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is highly dependent on the IDE / editor you use.

Comment: No, C/C++ doesn't support that. A specific editor may support it but not C/C++. Many editors support tags so that you can easy jump between definition, declaration, etc.

Comment: Generally it is not possible in C++ comments. This feature may be available in an IDE, but it would not be a language feature. Also it is possible in Doxygen generated manuals. Or it is reachable in repository view instruments available in githab, gitlab, bitbucket...

Comment: @Saad Does Visual studio support it??

Comment: @S.M. I am creating a Doxygen document for the code, when two functions have the same functionality, Instead of writing the comments again, I want to create a link so that it goes to the already existing comments

Comment: @4386427 Sure I will do that

Comment: `\link` is for this in Doxygen. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987292/insert-link-to-function-in-another-file-with-doxygen and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548701/handling-two-different-functions-with-the-same-name-in-doxygen

Comment: @Nithin I don't know about line numbers but you can ctrl+click a symbol to jump to its definition in VS  2017

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a link to method, you can use **empty function macro** to prevent compiler warnings, privates, etc.

Put **pseudo code** inside and follow by **F12** (Visual Studio) or similar key elsewhere.

Includes are often mandatory for jump to wanted method directly.

```
#define CALLERS(...)
#include "myClass.h"
#include "myFunctions.h"

CALLERS(myClass::myMethod; function();)
```